# Can the requestCode in intent be string in Android?

Tags: android

Below is the code from the official document from developer.android.com, especially the part explaining the intent.

Here, I faced confusions. In the declaring part, requestCode should be int right? but in the condition part, requestCode is compared with PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST, which definitely is not an int!

How should I think of this? Is PICK_CONTACT_RESULT some pre-declared data? 
But I also see lots of examples where customized statements are used just like the example below.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request it is that we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Here, requestCode is not int!
```

Comment: Why you think `PICK_CONTACT_RESULT` is not an `int` ? It has to be int otherwise its a compile error saying `Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'int', 'java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see from method signature that requestCode is an `int`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
```

So `PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST` cannot be String, Most probably it will be an integer variable defined somewhere in your class. You can `Ctrl` + `Click` on variable name and it will take you to where it is declared.